# How to run "npm publish" from outside of package directory

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, automation

I want to run `npm publish` in automated script .

I try `--prefix` option , it does not work :

```
npm publish --prefix /path/to/package;
```

Comment: `( cd /path/to/package && npm publish; )` maybe?